# Linq statement VB.NET List

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list

I have a list of increasing integer n1, n2, n3, ...ni... n100. I want to write a linq statement and/or lambda expression to do the following: Given an integer n, search through the list and get back 2 contiguous items in the list ni and n(i+1) such that n(i) <= n <= n(i+1). How can I do that using Linq statement in VB.NET ? I already know how to do it using normal for loop. But I want to use Linq statement. Thank you in advance.

I want to learn the equivalence between normal For Loop and Linq statement in this particular case.

Edit: I've already done it using normal For Loop as follows:

```
   Sub Get2Items(ByVal List As List(Of Integer), ByVal n As Integer, ByRef item1 As Integer, ByRef item2 As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To List.Count - 2
     If List(i) <= n AndAlso n <= List(i + 1) Then
        item1 = List(i)
        item2 = List(i + 1)
        Exit For
     End If
    Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: Furthermore, why do you want to do this in LINQ? If you've got it in a `for` loop already, that sounds like it's probably a preferable alternative. Just because something is doable in LINQ, does not mean that it should be done in LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this originally in C# and converted it to VB using DotNetFiddle, so it might be wrong syntactically in one or two places, but this is the gist.

In essence, I [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) the input list together with an offsetted version of itself (which means you want to make sure you're doing this only on safely-reenumerated `IEnumerable`s, or else calling `ToArray()` at the beginning to set another variable for use. This isn't an issue since your parameter type is `List(Of Integer)`, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to change that to `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` to have a stronger contract and more usability.) I zip them into an anonymous type for temporary storage, before filtering based on the condition you set in your original `for` loop.

```
Dim zipped = List.Zip(List.Skip(1), Function(a, b) New With {.A = a, .B = b})
Dim ret = zipped.Where(Function(c) c.A <= n AndAlso n <= c.B)
For Each v In ret
    item1 = v.A
    item2 = v.B
Next
```

It'd probably be better to return an `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))`, in which case you could just call a different `.Select` on `ret` to return the correct type, rather than dealing with the `ByRef` parameters like you're doing.